# assembly AND instruction and c++ equivalent?

Tags: c++, assembly

Solved.Thanks for help , saw a really good example on the net...but was the back few pages on google search engine ~~

i was reading some online tutorial on assembly by googling but i cant seem to figure out what they meant when they showed the AND instruction.

Can someone explain to me its usage ?
What is its equivalent c++ operator?

Also i cant understand what the operator "!" in c++ is used for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the thing is i dont understand the technical terms as i find them more confusing as compared to when i try to understand examples

Comment: If it was clearer than my answer, please post it.

Answer (score 5):

A bitwise and, means that you compare each bit of one operand with the corresponding bit of the other operand, and set the result to 1 if they are both 1, or 0 otherwise.  So consider these two bytes and'ed together:

```
  00000011
& 00000101
----------
  00000001
```

Only the lowest order bit is set in the result, because only for that bit position were the operands both 1.

In Intel x86 assembly languages you use the "and" operator to achieve this:

```
mov    eax, [op1]   ; eax is a register
and    eax, [op2]   ; now eax is the bitwise 'and' of the two.
mov    [result], eax
```

In C++

```
unsigned result = op1 & op2;
```

Logical and works differently.  Rather than and-ing each bit, we use a convention that a value is "false" if it is zero, and "true if it's not".  This is a convention of the higher level language, it is not an assembly language concept.  So in x86 we have:

```
    mov    eax, [op1]
    test   eax, eax  ; Test if eax is zero by anding it with itself.
    jz     isfalse   ; just to isfalse if the first operand is false

    mov    eax, [op2]
    test   eax, eax
    jnz    istrue

isfalse:
    mov    [result], 0
    jmp    done
istrue:
    mov    [result], 1

done:
    ...
```

Here this code uses the convention that 0 is false and 1 means true.

The C++ equivalent is:

```
boolean result = op1 && op2;
```